# How to alter context ("unified") on `git difftool`?

Tags: git, git-diff, vimdiff, git-difftool

I tried `-U9`("--unified") and `git config --global diff.context` - it affects only `git diff` but neither `git difftool` (I prefer vimdiff) nor `git commit -p` (commit by hunks).

Answer (score 1):

Add this into .vimrc:
`:set diffopt=filler,context:9`

See more at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'diffopt'

Also you can toggle fold:

> The command **zc** will close a fold (if the cursor is in an open fold),
>   and **zo** will open a fold. It's easier to just use **za** which will toggle the current fold (close it if it was open, or open it if it was closed).
>   Source: https://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding

[image: git difftool vimdiff folding golang]